# Can we control Jmeter's components through Beanshell? I want to disable all assertions through one flag. how can I do it?

Tags: jmeter

Can we control Jmeter's components through `Beanshell`? I want to disable all assertions through one flag.  How can I do it?

If any other solution than `beanShell` then let me know.

Comment: logged an enhancement in bugzilla. bug link https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my knowledge, you can not disable all Assertions in the Test Plan by using `BeanShell`

The work around is as follows:

1. Create a variable as `processAssertions` in `User Defined Variable` config element.
2. Keep All Assertions inside If Controllers.
3. Add condition as `${processAssertions}==true`, so Assertions will be evaluated **ONLY** when you set the `processAssertions` value to `true`. Set any value other than `true`, to make JMeter to **ignore** Assertions.

---

Using Bean Shell Assertion:

Pre-condition: create `processAssertions` (Set to `TRUE`) in `User Defined Variables`

```
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.ResponseAssertion; 
log.info("hello"); 
try{ 
    ResponseAssertion obj = new ResponseAssertion(); 
    if(${processAssertions}==TRUE) { // value accessed from UDV
        log.info("inside if");  
        obj.Enabled=false;
        SampleResult.setSuccessful(true); // set sample result to PASS, set to false to mark it failure.

    }   
} catch(Exception e) { 

}
```

---

If Controller - with assertions:
[image]

If Controller - without assertions:
[image]

References:

1. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps
2. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions

Comment: Thank you. But this is possible only if I write all Beanshell assertions , right? I have one recorded URL(suppose for login into the website whose response is json) and under that I have put my json response assertion. The problem is I cannot put If controller under that URL.(as it is not giving me an option of controller on right click). If I put if controller above URL and userdefined variable for assertion is set to False. then URL itself wont run.I need to run URL. Can you help me in this?

Comment: I have tried Beanshell sampler like follows: import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.ResponseAssertion;
log.info("hello");
try{
 ResponseAssertion obj = new ResponseAssertion();
 
 
 if(${RunWithAssertion}==TRUE)
 {
  log.info("inside if");   
  obj.Enabled=false;
 } 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 
}
but It is giving Error .Any Idea about it?

Comment: 1) what I said is different approach. Keep any Assertion (not just Bean Shell Sampler) in `If Controller`. You can NOT keep `If Controller` inside `HTTP Sampler`, keep it inside the `Controller` in which `HTTP Sampler` is present and let me know if any issue. 2) what you tried using Bean Shell Assertion is also works, but you have to write the condition and manually set the SampleResult either `PASS/FAIL`. updated the code in answer. pls try out.

Comment: My structure is as follows:  1.MyTestPlan(TestPlan)

Comment: My structure is :  
1.MyTestPlan(TestPlan)                                                             
     1.1 Cookie Manager
     1.2 UserDefined  Variable(processAssertions =true)
     1.3 Operations(Thread Group)
        1.3.1 Transaction Controller(Login)
              1.3.1.1 Recorded URL(Http sampler) 
                  1.3.1.1.1 Css Extractor
                   1.3.1.1.2 Json Assertion
as You Are saying If  I put IF controller  inside 1.3.1.1(login) How will My URL run? I just want to disble assertion. I have many assertions in my script.The above is just sample script.

Comment: you better maintain two scripts with `Assertions` and without `Assertions`. Or you can try out `Taurus` tool as suggested by Dmitri. If both are satisfiable, then hardway is having two `If Controllers` , one for `HTTP samper with Assertions`, another is `ONLY HTTP Sampler`. added screenshot in the answer. please refer.

Comment: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``mport org.apache.jmeter.assertions.ResponseAssertion; log.info("hello"); try{ ,...... I am getting this error in the log while running beanshell.

Comment: `i` is missing in `import`, please check

Comment: import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.ResponseAssertion;
log.info("hello");
try{
  
 if(${RunWithAssertion}==TRUE)
 {
  log.info("inside if"); 
  log.info(obj.getName());
  this.Enabled=false;
   SampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
 } 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 
}

Comment: Ok. I have tried another one . try{
  
 if(${RunWithAssertion}==TRUE)
 {
  log.info("inside if"); 
  prev.setStopThread(true);
 }   
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 
}
  but this is stooping the entire thread. Do you know Any other method for skipping next step. Like we use CONTINUE in for loop

Comment: In comments, I am not able to understand the error. please add the code you tried to the question itself (using `edit` option) also add exception trace to the question.

Comment: Can you please provide me the information about how to enable and disable the jmeter's assertion using setEnabled() method.

Comment: And also i want to clear one point , I don't want two different scripts. Just one script which will run with assertion and without assertion (by using only one switch i.e; flag)

Comment: I don't have any idea related to `setEnabled`. there are three solutions 1) maintain two scripts 2) use `taurus` (Free) 3) use `If Controllers`  thats all I can say.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information.  I will Try it out.

Comment: Thanks Naveen . I have suggested The same thing to my mentor. But That will just double the all URL(though At a time only one If will run).My mentor doesn't want this.

Comment: Thank you so much . It was great help. Finally I have Found out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is running your JMeter test using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper, it naturally supports JMeter tests, moreover it provides some nice extensions.

Particular in your case you can use [Modifications for Existing Scripts](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) functionality which allows enabling or disabling Test Elements

```
---
scenarios:
  modification_example:
    script: /your/jmeter/testplan.jmx       
    modifications:
      disable:  # Names of the tree elements to disable
      - Response Assertion
      - Duration Assertion
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways in addition to previous answers:

1) Wrap assertions into If controllers, then - yes, set a flag var & check at the If block.

2) Run JMeter programmatically through JMeter API - here you'd have programmatic access to each and every element in the TestPlan.
Although that way is documented quite poorly while the API model is far from being clear itself.

UPD: some clues for the way of doing the latter

1) Here's the main reference: http://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html

2) Instantiate engine and load properties:

```
StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/jmeter.properties");
```

3) Instantiate SaveService and load your plan (yes, save service is what resposible for that)

```
SaveService.loadProperties();
File yourplan = new File("/path/to/yourplan.jmx");
HashTree planTree = SaveService.loadTree(yourplan);
```

4) Here's the point where you can access & work your plan elements, going through the [HashTree](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/package-summary.html), retrieving test elements in sub-hashtrees (for elements, see the reference mentioned in p.1) & changing them and/or the test structure (cast to TestElement must be good enough for [enabling/disabling](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/TestElement.html#setEnabled(boolean))).

5) As you got done with it, the rest is straightforward:

```
jmeter.configure(planTree);
jmeter.run();
```

That should be pretty much it.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide me sample program to control assertions.?

Comment: Ah... that would be quite a deal, as I mentioned, so I'm not going to write a whole bunch of code for you - although I'll try to give you some clue of a way of doing it, then you can catch up with working solution yourself.

Wait for update on my answer

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Where should I write this code? In the beanshell Preprocessor  or banshell postprocessor?

Comment: Thank you so much . It was great help. Finally I have Found out the solution.